# background worker current status

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am using background threads to run intense search processes in order to allow the UI to be fully accessible. After creating each bgw I update a datagridview which shows the different threads and current status. however once they complete, I have no way or at least I dont know of a way to update the status on the datagridview specific to each backgroundworker.

```
 Try
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync()
        queuelist.Enqueue(bgw)
        If Not Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Main Thread" Then
            Dim record As String() = {jobNum, clientProj & jobNum, jobStartTime,   bgw.IsBusy.ToString}
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(record)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("An Error Occured:" & vbNewLine & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

this sets the datagridviewer once the threads begin, but once it ends I dont know how to update or know which thread ended. I tried putting them into a queue but I cannot identify a specific worker when i dequeue.

any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't understand why you'd make implementation details like background workers visible on the user interface.  Well, some code.  It doesn't make sense to use a Queue, threads do not end in any predictable order.  Let's do a list:

```
Dim workerList As New List(Of BackgroundWorker)
```

You want to take advantage of the RunWorkerCompleted event raised by BGW to know when the job is done.  So use AddHandler:

```
    Dim bgw As New BackgroundWorker
    AddHandler bgw, AddressOf DoSomeWork
    AddHandler bgw, AddressOf WorkDone
    workerList.Add(bgw)
    '' Do something with the grid
    ''...
    bgw.RunWorkerAsync()
```

And the event handler can look like this:

```
Private Sub WorkDone(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    If e.Error IsNot Nothing Then Throw e.Error
    Dim bgw = DirectCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)
    workerList.Remove(bgw)
    '' Do something with the grid
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and btw, I need to display each process running on the UI as the current state of each job like this:        jobId  jobname  starttime  status